# Powerquery/Formula to calculate existing delays , new delays and out of delays

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a manufacturing plant data on a daily basis and specific vehicle (denoted by sno) belonging to a specific category (mmodel) that can go on a delay due to some issues.

Now my Input tab has the snapshot of this data on a daily basis and denotes the vehicle (combination of sno and mmodel) that might be a new delay in comparison to the previous day (new delay implies that the vehicle combination dint exist on the immediate previous day to the day in comparison) ; existing delay - the same vehicle combination existed on the previous day or Off delay -the vehicle combination for the previous day doesn't exist today (or the day in consideration).

The numbers for the current day are calculated based on the vehicle entries on the current day and the immediate previous day.

The first day is the day of reference where all entries are just delays and nor off delay or new delay...The subsequent days entries are compared with the immediate previous day to get the delays ,new delays and off delay... The output tab 1 is a summary view by snapshot date and the output 2 tab is a view by master model and snapshot date.

Can you please help me here.

The earliest date in my data (ascending order) would be considered as the date of reference. So in this case 03/01/2022 would be considered as the date of reference where all the unique entries (an entry is denoted by the combination of sno and mmodel) would be considered just delays.

So when I consider 03/02/2022 the common entries between 03/02/2022 and the previous day which is 03/01/2022 would be the delays which are in data (r123,S1234) ,(y123,D2123) and (W321,G345)

The entries existing in 03/01/2022 but not in 03/02/2022 would be considered as off-delays which are in my case (r3421,S1234) ,(g21q,D2123) and (E231,G345).

The entries that are completely new in 03/02/2022 but not in 03/01/2022 would be (D891,S1234) and (K1231,J1231) which are considered as new delays...

[Input tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEBIO.png)

[Output tab 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3GPM.png)

[Output tab 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9cJp.png)

Following is what I have tried

[Lookup to get the last occurrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqHJt.png)
[Lookup to get the first occurrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C61I8.png)

Also attached the calculation explanation...The entries from the previous day needs to be compared and referenced to the current day of reference..

[Calculation explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2utK.png)

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Hi harrymc ..I have updated my try above..

Comment: This can be done using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and O365.  Output tab 1 is relatively straight-forward.  But I don't understand how you derive your Output tab 2.  I can't figure out how it derives from your Input tab.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: The data in output 2 is basically pivoted on column mmodel and snapshot_date..Every mmodel has multiple sno...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

Since you request two different tables for output, I have actually created three queries:

1. **dailyReport** processes the daily report and creates a table with the various delay statuses.
2. **Snapshot Summary** takes the daily report and process it to create the summary.
3. **Delay by Model** takes the daily report and processes it to create that report.

Once this has been created, all you need do in the future is change the `daily report` and select to refresh the queries.

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see.
- Then add two more queries "from blank" and paste the relevant code.
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***Daily Report***
[image]

**dailyReport**
*rename this query: `dailyReport`*
*Load to: Connection only*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"sno", type text}, 
        {"mmodel", type text}, 
        {"snapshot_date", type date}}),

//generate list of all the dates in this report
    allDates = List.Dates(List.Min(#"Changed Type"[snapshot_date]),
                Duration.Days(List.Max(#"Changed Type"[snapshot_date])-List.Min(#"Changed Type"[snapshot_date]))+1,
                #duration(1,0,0,0)),

//group by sno and mmodel
    //If the first date in allDates is in snapshot_date then Delay=true
    //If a date in allDates is in snapshot_date and preceding date in allDates is in snapshot_date then Delay=true
    //If a date in allDates is in snapshot_date and preceding date in allDates not in snapshot_date then New Delay=true
    //if a date in allDates is NOT in snapshot_date and preceding date in allDates IS in snapshot_date then off Delay=true
    group = Table.Group(#"Changed Type",{"sno", "mmodel"},{
        {"Delay Status", (t)=>List.Generate(
            ()=>[ds=if List.Contains(t[snapshot_date],allDates{0}) then 
                [date=allDates{0}, Delay=true, off Delay=false, new Delay=false]
                else [date=allDates{0}, Delay=false, off Delay=false, new Delay=false],
                idx=0],
            each [idx] < List.Count(allDates),
            each [ds=
                if List.Contains(t[snapshot_date],allDates{[idx]+1}) 
                    and not List.Contains(t[snapshot_date],allDates{[idx]})            
                then 
                    [date=allDates{[idx]+1}, Delay=false, off Delay=false, new Delay=true]

                else if List.Contains(t[snapshot_date],allDates{[idx]+1}) 
                        and List.Contains(t[snapshot_date],allDates{[idx]})
                    then 
                        [date=allDates{[idx]+1}, Delay=true, off Delay=false, new Delay=false] 

                else if List.Contains(t[snapshot_date],allDates{[idx]}) 
                        and not List.Contains(t[snapshot_date],allDates{[idx]+1})
                    then [date=allDates{[idx]+1}, Delay=false, off Delay=true, new Delay= false]

                else [date=allDates{[idx]+1}, Delay=false, off Delay=false, new Delay=false],
                
                idx=[idx]+1],
            each [ds]), type list}
        }),
    #"Expanded Delay Status" = Table.ExpandListColumn(group, "Delay Status"),
    #"Expanded Delay Status1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Delay Status", "Delay Status", {"date", "Delay", "off Delay", "new Delay"}, {"date", "Delay", "off Delay", "new Delay"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Delay Status1",{{"date", type date}, {"Delay", type logical}, {"off Delay", type logical}, {"new Delay", type logical}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

**Snapshot summary**

```
let
    Source = dailyReport,
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"date"}, {
        {"Delay", each List.Count(List.Select([Delay], each _ = true)), Int64.Type},
        {"off Delay", each List.Count(List.Select([off Delay], each _ = true)), Int64.Type},
        {"new Delay", each List.Count(List.Select([new Delay], each _ = true)), Int64.Type}
    })
    
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

***Snapshot Summary***
[image]

**Delay by Model**

```
let
    Source = dailyReport,

//don't need sno column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"sno"}),

//convert true and false to 1 and 0
    xForm = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns",{
        {"Delay", Number.From},
        {"off Delay", Number.From},
        {"new Delay", Number.From}
    }),

//Group by date and mmmodel
// then extract the delay statuses
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(xForm, {"date", "mmodel"}, {
        {"Delay", each List.Sum([Delay]),Int64.Type},
        {"off Delay", each List.Sum([off Delay]), Int64.Type},
        {"new Delay", each List.Sum([new Delay]), Int64.Type}}),

//remove rows with no data
    remRows = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows",
        each [Delay]<>0 or [off Delay]<>0 or [new Delay]<>0),

//Could also implement a custom sort if the mmodel sort is critical
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(remRows,{
        {"date", Order.Ascending}, {"Delay", Order.Descending}, {"off Delay", Order.Descending}, {"new Delay", Order.Descending}}),

//replace zeros with nulls
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Sorted Rows",0,null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Delay", "off Delay", "new Delay"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

***by Model***
[image]

As this setup is moderately complex if you don't have experience in Power Query, I have [uploaded a workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Aml6o6HIc9uOvVEC_IziR2xDLVbK?e=ojfiGt) with the data and code for your perusal.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ron Rosenfeld!...This is of great help!!...

Answer (score 0):

To determine a range for a specific date, say 3/2/2022:

```
=INDEX(A:A, XMATCH(DATEVALUE("3/2/2022"),C:C, 0,1)):INDEX(A:A, XMATCH(DATEVALUE("3/2/2022"),C:C, 0,-1))
```

Assuming each date section is continuous. Also make sure your dates are store as dates and not text. A simple test is `=A2+1` must give you the next day's date, where A2 is a date.

To determine if todays ID is in yesterday's range, say for row 10

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(A:A, XMATCH(C10 - 1,C:C, 0,1)):INDEX(A:A, XMATCH(C10 - 1,C:C, 0,-1)), A10)
```

If the above is > 0, its a previous delay and if its = 0 its a new delay.

For off delay you have to look forward to "tomorrow's" range

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(A:A, XMATCH(C10 + 1,C:C, 0,1)):INDEX(A:A, XMATCH(C10 + 1,C:C, 0,-1)), A10) = 0
```

For these formulae I assumed the ID is in column A, but technically you must combine the two columns in a helper column

```
=A2&B2
```

Comment: Hi @Mobus!...Really appreciate your response!..Can you please share your excel file too..When I try to execute the formulas I am getting the error -You have entered too many arguments for this function

Comment: Haha that happens if you don't have a test file and simply hard code it on superuser :) Let me see what I did wrong...

Comment: My bad, I confused INDEX and OFFSET input parameters! Corrected!

Comment: The above answer is useful if you actually want the range for each date for other calculations. However if you don't have Office 365 with XMATCH (to find the last date in a range using reverse direction search, you have to use `INDEX(..., MATCH(...)):INDEX(..., MATCH(...)+COUNTIF(...))` or use `OFFSET(INDEX(..., MATCH(...)),0,0,COUNTIF(...),1)`. The former being quite CPU intensive and the latter (while one less MATCH) being volatile (i.e. OFFSET recalculates all the time).

Answer (score 0):

This implementation uses COUNTIFS which is available in Excel 2010 and newer.

To determine if todays ID in column A is in yesterday's date range (column C), say for row 10

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A10,C:C,C10 - 1)
```

If the above is > 0, its an existing delay and if its = 0 its a new delay.

For off delay you have to look forward to "tomorrow's" data

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A10,C:C,C10 + 1)=0
```

Which will return TRUE if "today's" ID does not exist in "tomorrow's" data.

Lastly, this formula counts the number of off-delays in one go

```
=SUM(ISERROR(MATCH(IF(C:C=C10-1,A:A,""),IF(C:C=C10,A:A,""),0))*1)                 ...Array formula: Press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER in version prior to Excel 365
```

Ps. for all these formulae I assumed the unique ID is in column A, but technically you must combine the two columns in a helper column to form a unique ID

```
=A2&B2
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mobus!..Really appreciate your help!